# How to prevent model clashes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this example I reproduced situation when two directives use same name for `ng-model` and that resulting in values in their inputs are linked.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aF5DtMVyQ27Rgb7ximEw?p=preview

COde:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('formOne', function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'E',
    'template': "<form name='formOne'><input type='text' ng-model='myValue'></form>"
  };
});

app.directive('formTwo', function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'E',
    'template': "<form name='formTwo'><input type='text' ng-model='myValue'></form>"
  };
});
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  //stuff
});
```

HTML:

```
  <div ng-controller='MyController'>
    <h1>Input something</h1>
    <form-one></form-one>
    <form-two></form-two>
  </div>
```

What re a conventional ways to prevent such things? Links to official sources will be very appreciated. There also can be some official naming conventions - they will be appreciated as well

Comment: That's why you want to use isolated scopes for your directives.

Comment: @dfsq What is isolated scopes? How to achieve this?

Comment: Read about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-terminal-).

Comment: @dfsq Cool! I will accept it if you post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the situation why you want to use [isolated scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-terminal-) for your directives.

```
app.directive('formOne', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<form name='formOne'><input type='text' ng-model='myValue'>{{myValue}}</form>"
    };
});
```

#### Fixed demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/IZWZhwtfclZKMnnNNFA9?p=preview

Comment: Its worth to add that with `scope: true` regular scope for a directive will be created, and with `scope: {}` - isolated scope. Regular scope works for my example, but I think it will not work if I had nested forms - so isolated scope (with `{}`) must be choosen here - it is an ultimate solution for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use an isolated scope, so any models will be only for that scope. 
The previous solution brings the problem to "how do I get my data from the directive?", two solutions:

- Use isolated scope with = bindings (see [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), the scope section)
- Use an event to send the info